# Shnayim Ushloshim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred thirty-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yosef was sold 232 years before the Exodus. (He was separated from Yaakov for 22 years, and then Yaakov and his descendants spent 210 years in Egypt.)

Answer (score 1):

To add to Alex's answer. The Gematria of נבוא אני ואמך ואחיך is 232

Comment: As has been pointed out to me by several people, this question, like all in the series, is not seeking gematriot.

Answer (score 1):

The name Yosef appears 232 times in Tanach.

Answer (score 1):

King Achav led a legion of 232 young sons of officers into battle against Ben-Hadad King of Aram, based on a prophecy from God, and was victorious. ([Kings I 20:15](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.20.15))